# maximun & minimun

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Determine the global extreme values of the function
$$f(x,y)=2x^{3}+2x^{2}y+3y^{2}, \:\:\: x,y\geqslant 0, \: x+y\leq 1$$
find f(min) & f(max)
so far, I got:
$$f_{x}=6x^{2}+4xy\:; \: f_{y}=2x^{2}+6y$$
set $$f_{x} = 0 \: and  \: f_{y} = 0$$ and solve for x and y. $$\begin{align}f_{x}=6x^{2}+4xy = 0 \\solve\:for\:x\:,\:2x(3x
+2y)=0\\\rightarrow x=0, -\frac{-2y}{3}\end{align}$$ next, $$\begin{align}f_{y}=2x^{2}+6y=0\\solve\:for\:y\:,\: y = -\frac{x^{2}}{3}\end{align}$$ plug $$x=0, -\frac{-2y}{3}$$ into $$y = -\frac{x^{2}}{3}$$ to get y values, which I got $$ y = 0, \frac{9}{2}$$ Now, I got three pairs, which are $$(0,0)\:,\:(0,1)\:[since\: x\geq0\:and\:x+y\leq1]\:,\:(0,\frac{9}{2})$$ Plug all of them into f(x,y) individually, I got$$ 0, 3, and\: \frac{243}{4}(60.75)$$ Therefore, f(min) = 0 and f(max) = 60.75. The answer is not correct, but I don't where I got it wrong. Could anyone help me to point it out, please?
Many Thanks!

Comment: Any point satisfying $\triangledown f = 0$ is a *critical point*, which might or might not mean the point is a minimum/maximum. They could be saddle points too, for example. So it is not enough to compare $P_1$, $P_2, P_3$ and say the maximum of them is a maximum and their minimum is a minimum. 

To know whether they are indeed maximums or minimums, use the discriminant test.

Comment: @lafinur, the problem is that if my points are not correct, then second derivative test won't work.

Comment: If your points are not correct, there isn't any test that will work. Just make sure you are calculating them right.

Comment: @lafinur, that's where I need help. I feel like I made a mistake somewhere, but I don't know where. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global extrema can also appear on the border of the domain. We have to check independently stationary points on the lines $$x=0, y=0, y=1-x,$$  and also the points which are the corners of the domain $$(0,0),(0,1),(1,0).$$ Clearly, zero is the minimum. The maximum is finally $f(0,1)=3.$

Comment: Thank you! when y = 9/2, then y = 1-x would not work. Therefore, the only possible points are (0,0) and (0,1).

Comment: Exactly. $(0,9/2)$ does not belong to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

No differential calculus is needed due to the property that each term has a positive coefficient. We have $$0\le f(x,y)=2x^2(x+y)+3y^2\\ \le 2x^2+3y^2\le 2x+3y\\ =2(x+y)+y\le 2+y\le 3$$ and $f(0,1)=3. $ Therefore the maximal value is equal $3$ and the minimal value is $f(0,0)=0.$

Comment: The last term should be $3y^2$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. Corrected. I am watching World Cup in Soccer and cannot concentrate on details. By the way USA is playing against Nederlands  :)

Answer (score 0):

A quite elementary approach:

Let $D = \{(x,y)\mid x,y\geq0, x+y\leq 1\}$ and $f(x,y)=2x^{3}+2x^{2}y+3y^{2}$.

First note that we clearly have $f(x,y)\geq 0 =f(0,0)$ for all $(x,y)\in D$. Moreover, if $(x,y)\neq 0$, then $f(x,y)>0$. It follows that *$0$ is the minimum* of $f$ with $(0,0)$ as *unique global minimizer*.

Let $(x,y)\in D$ and $\alpha = x+y$. If $0<\alpha <1$, then $f(x,y)< f(x/\alpha ,y/\alpha)$. Therefore, if $(x^*,y^*)$ is a global maximizer of $f$ on $D$, we must have $x^*+y^*=1$, i.e. $(x^*,y^*) =(x^*,1-x^*)$.

Now, let $x\in [0,1]$, then we have
$f(x,1-x)=5x^2-6x+3=x(5x-6)+3$. If $x\neq 0$, then $x(5x-6)<0$ and therefore the global maximum is must be attained at $x^*=0$. We conclude that *$3$ is the maximum* of $f$ with *unique global maximizer* $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.